# Polynomials evaluating to primitive elements

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, primitive-elements

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field generated over the rational by some number $\alpha$, of degree $d$.

I'd like to know and understand the the set of polynomials $f(X)\in \mathbf{Q}[X]$  with $f(\alpha)$ again a primitive element of $K$.  All linear polynomials of course belong to this collection.

If the degree $d$ is a prime number then I could easily find the following answer:
If $f(\alpha)$ is irrational then it has the same degree as $\alpha$.(ie the remainder when $f(X)$ is divided by the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ should be nonconstant).

By changing $\alpha$ to $\beta=\alpha+m$ for suitable integer $m$ I could show that
all $aX^k+b$  with $a,b\in\mathbf{Q},a\neq0$ belong to this collection (ie. the degree of the algebraic numbers  $\beta^k$
for any positive integer $k$ is the same as that of $\beta$).

Is anything else known about this?

Comment: The assertion in the fourth paragraph isn't true in general: E.g. $\beta=\sqrt[4]{2}$ has degree $4$ over the rationals, while $\beta^2$ has degree $2$. If the set of $f$ you want to describe is intended to depend on $K$ and on $\alpha$, then you can't change $\alpha$ to $\beta$ without changing the set. Or did you intend the opposite order of quantifiers - one single set of $f$ that should work for all irrational $\alpha$ and all their $K$ at once?

Comment: @GNiklasch   I see that the collection of polynomials depends on the choice of  primitive element. So your 'counter-example' is the one I tried to avoid  by adding an integer constant.  So $\sqrt[4]2 +m$ and all its powers will be degree 4 (I guess for all $m\neq 0$).  I would like a primitive element for given K  that gives  in some sense a "large collection of polynomials" evaluating to again a primitive element.

Comment: OK. But keeping $K$ fixed and varying $\alpha$ by an invertible affine-linear substitution cannot make the set of interest any smaller or larger, nor make it essentially different! -  the corresponding sets of polynomials will be in bijection via the inverse substitution.- I do not expect these sets to have much usable structure unless either $K$ is known a priori to lack any nontrivial subfields or $K$ is normal over the rationals and you have some control over the Galois group and the subfields.